# Why is the stream interrupted?

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, video-streaming, vlc

Task: endlessly play video files from the folder to work screens.
I decided to use Ubuntu Server, Nginx+RTMP_MODULE, Ffmpeg.

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Jammy

```
uname -a
Linux streamserver 5.15.0-89-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP
```

/nginx.conf/

```
worker_process 1;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

# RTMP configuration
rtmp {
    server{
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4096;
        
        application live {
            live on;
            record off;
        }
    }
}
```

/bash.sh/

```
#!/bin/bash

directory_video="/home/stream_server/VideoStream"
stream="rtmp://localhost/live"

while :
do
    name_video=$(ls $directory_video|sort -R|head -1) #take video name
    
    ffmpeg -re -i $directory_video/$name_video \
    -b:v 3000k                                 \
    -f flv -flvflags no_duration_filesize      \
    rtmp://localhost/live
done
```

When starting the script bash.sh everything goes well.
The problem arises when the player tries to start the next video.
For some reason, the player launches only the first few frames after which the picture stops on them.

What am I missing?

I tried to launch FFMPEG separately from the script, changed various speed settings, bitrate, and resolution.

No matter what I do the problem, it is saved as it is.

Comment: Things you can try... **1.** Make sure all videos in `$directory_video/$name_video` are encoded with the same settings (same codec, resolution, FPS, etc). **2.** If they are not all same. then you need to add some new re-encoding options, so all the output matches in format/settings so finally the output playing side now sees no difference in data type.  A possible solution is to have your `-b:v 3000k` backed by other encode options like `-vf scale=640:360` (for a global resolution) and `-c:v libx264` and `-pix_fmt yuv420p` before finally setting that `-f flv` as the output format.